# Problema al tratar de obtener y eliminar una session en laravel con $request->session()->get('cart') y Session::get('cart')

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, payu

estoy desarrollando una tienda online con Payu Latam, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando payu me confirme una compra yo pueda vaciar el carrito de compras de dicho usuario comprador.

El proceso es el sig...

Envio los datos de la compra a la pasarela de Payu por ende los usuarios salen de mi tienda, payu verifica los datos y procede a dejar pagar al usuario, una vez el usuario paga, payu lo redirige a la ulr de respuesta de mi pagina ejemplo::`www.mipagina.com/respuesta`, aqui se le informará hacerca de su compra, esta pagina es solo informativa. Por otro lado existe otra url llamada `www.mipagina.com/confirmation`, a esta pagina se enviaran los datos con los cuales podre actualizar el sistema, estos datos se envían con el metodos POST.

A `/confirmation` llega una variable llamada `$state_pol` que debe ser igual a 4 para poder hacer lo sig...

```
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function confirmation(Request $request) {
    $state_pol = $_POST['state_pol'];
    if($state_pol == 4) {
        // Eliminar carrito
        session()->forget('cart');

        //Informar en un archivo que el carrito fue elimado
        $fp = fopen('pruebas.txt', "a");
        fwrite($fp, "Carrito eliminado \r\n");
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

El problema es que al parecer no se esta ejecutando la linea de eliminación del carrito, he probado de varias formas, usando `use Session;` y `Session::forget('cart')`.
Estaba haciendo pruebas para ver si en vez de eliminarlo lo obtengo y una vez obtenido el carrito guardo en un archivo .txt que si hay elementos, asi...

```
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function confirmation(Request $request) {
    // No funcionó con ninguna de estas formas
    //$cart = $request->session()->get('cart');
    //$cart = session()->get('cart');
    //$cart = Session::get('cart');

    if( isset($cart) ) {
        $fp = fopen('pruebas.txt', "a");
        fwrite($fp, "Hay algo en carrito \r\n");
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

Ahora, tengo que mensionar que Payu envía los datos a la pagina de confirmación si esa url es publica, es decir, esta en un servidor público, yo lo subí a un servidor de prueba en heroku, otra cosa es que esa url no debe tener ningún tipo de verificación como lo que usa Laravel 5.6, osea @csrf, por lo cual lo descative para esa ulr en específico.

Todo esto funciona perfectamente en local incluso con el @csrf desactivado, el obtener el carrito y eliminarlo funcionan, con todos y cada una de las formas especificadas arriba.

De antemano muchas gracias, espero puedan ayudarme, si neceistan mas información solo digan.

Comment: Hay varios problemas en el código... Por un lado : $state_pol = $request->get("nombre_Del_Input"); por otro lado, quieres recoger los datos de una sesion, que nunca inicializas

Comment: Hola EduBw, no es necesario poner el nombre del input, de hecho con $_POST funciona perfectamente, por otro lado, las sessiones si estan inicializadas desde otros archivo atras, en este archivo solo es recoger dicha session, no hace falta inicializar nada ya que esta inicializada de forma global y con el ayudante session de obtiene, no hace falta usar algo como: session_start(), y para terminar tambien digo al final que dicho codigo funciona perfectamente en local, entonces no se que este mal, espero haberme explicado.

Comment: saludos, he trabajado con Laravel, no te preocupes, sin embargo, sino muestras donde y como estás iniciando la variable en la sesión, el código es incompleto , ya que podría estar por ahí el problema. al igual que no usar $request->get("nombre_Del_Input"); ya que Laravel te envuelve la respuesta y más seguro.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema con payu y php con la pagina de confirmación que no se ejecuta el contenido de mi carro de compras que está hecho con $_SESSION ¿Has encontrado alguna solución?

Answer (score 0):

Yo he utilizado [el shopping cart de darryldecode](https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart#usage)  y me ha funcionado muy bien, te quitas todos esos problemas, tiene buena documentación.